# Open the map app of the device with an address in Cordova

Tags: cordova, maps

On Android it's possible to open the [Google Maps app via an intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) with native code. iOS has their own native way of open [their Maps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452207-openmaps). Using those Api within Cordova would require native code. Is there an easier way to open the map app of the device for a particular address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [launchnavigator](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator) plugin. It allows you to call `launchnavigator.navigate` which will open the available apps that can be used (both Android and iOS). You can also specify a [specific app](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#advanced-usage) as well.